# Swagger codegen not generating JAXB annoted model classes

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, swagger, swagger-codegen

I want to build a REST service which will consume and produce data in XML format.

I used swagger editor to create the yaml file and specified application/xml at the basePath section :

> consumes:
>     - application/xml
>
> produces:
>     - application/xml

I need my generated model pojos to be annotated with JAXB annotations (like @XmlRootElement)

But when I generated the server side code with the swagger codegen, my model POJO classes were missing the JAXB annotations.

Can someone please help me here ? May be I am missing something ?

Swagger codegen development team suggests a workaround for this issue :

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/9052

Do we really need to do this ?